# Kubernetes permission denied error on config.lock

Tags: kubernetes

I try to change default context in kubernetes but I get `config.lock: permission denied` error.

```
$ kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=custom_namespace 
error: open /home/vagrant/.kube/config.lock: permission denied
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that `kubernetes config directory` has the same permissions as `kubernetes config file`.

**Solution** Beside, steps specified in [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#more-information).

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Add change permissions on `$HOME/.kube/` directory.

```
$ sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/
```

Comment: Had to use chown -R

Comment: @Lukasz, what about for jenkins user? I am facing similar error while switching context in jenkins. I stored config file as a secret therefore there is no any config file $HOME/.kube

Comment: I assume that you want to automatize deployments with **jenkins.io**  and that a jenkins user has no home directory.  Then, what if you create a home directory for jenkins user? Theoretically, you should solve this problem. On side, I've done automatic deployments yet so my knowledge of this subject is limited at this point.

Comment: this was money. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A reason that this could happen is an incorrect KUBECONFIG environmental variable. You can easily solve that by setting the variable to nothing/empty like this on power shell:

```
$env:KUBECONFIG=""
```

and verify it like this:

```
$env:KUBECONFIG
```

Alternatively, solve it by setting the KUBECONFIG environmental variable like:

```
$env:KUBECONFIG="C:\Users\your_user_name\.kube\config"
```

Its also explained here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/493

Answer (score -2):

if you are on windows system. try to run command as administrator.

this fix error.
`open .lock: access is denied.`

Comment: It is not good practice running commands as a privileged user unnecessarily (mainly for security reasons). Running `kubectl` should usually not require running as administrator.

Comment: didnt fix it for me.